# Rails - Make (Reversed) Nested Form Save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm seeing a lot of stuff about saving with nested forms, but all of them have the opposite relationship than mine.  Customer Info belongs_to User, but I want to update the user email from Customer Info.  Right now the view is working, it's just not saving.

I have the following relationships defined:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :customer_info, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :customer_info
end

class CustomerInfo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  attr_accessible :user, :email
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user
end
```

And the following nested form:

```
%h1 Editing customer_info

= form_for @customer_info, :validate => true do |f|
  - if @customer_info.errors.any?
    #error_explanation
      %h2= "#{pluralize(@customer_info.errors.count, "error")} prohibited this user from being saved:"
      %ul
        - @customer_info.errors.full_messages.each do |msg|
          %li= msg

  %h2 Your Profile

  = fields_for @user do |i|
    .field
      = i.label :email, 'Email'
      = i.text_field :email

  .field
    = f.label :username, "Username"
    = f.text_field :username

  .actions
    = f.submit 'Next'
```

Comment: First thing i see: "has_one :customer_info, dependent: :destroy" should be "has_one :customer_info, :dependent => :destroy

Comment: @SG86, why - that's perfectly fine using the 1.9 hash syntax

Comment: I thought the call to `fields_for` had to be made from the `has_one` model to the `belongs_to` model? In this case, the form_for should be `form_for @user` and then fields_for should be `fields_for @customer_info` (or maybe even `fields_for :customer_info`, since it's an association.  I could be completely wrong on that requirement though

Comment: Can anyone confirm that?  I'd really prefer to not go through the user if I'm only updating one field.

Comment: In other news, I tried switching it around, so that user wrapped customer_info, and I remembered why I switched in the first place.  It's giving me an error: "Password can't be blank," when it's not even a field on the page... ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it actually was saving through something I did along the way, I was just using devise, so it wasn't letting me just change the email in the database, I had to confirm.

Thanks to [Ahmad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1856239/ahmad-sherif) for encouraging me to CHECK OUT THE CONSOLE to get a better idea of what was happening.

Answer (score 1):

Though it's an unusual approach to do what you want this way, but we need to know what's your code on the controller side. I'll assume you use the usual Rails scaffold like this

```
def update
  if @customer_info.update_attributes params[:customer_info]
    # the rest of the assumed code
  end
end
```

If so, try adding `autosave` option to you `belongs_to :user` relation, so that it gets saved after successfully saving the CustomerInfo, e.g.

```
 belongs_to :user, autosave: true
```

Comment: Yes, that's what my update method looks like in my customer_info controller.  I added that bit, and no luck. =(

Comment: Just noticed that you use fields_for method directly, you need to use it like this `f.fields_for :user`

Comment: when I do that, I get this:
`User(#70183445941760) expected, got ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess(#70183399964320)`

Comment: I did edit my last comment because of a typo, `@user` became `:user`, you get this error using the symbol `:user`?

Comment: Gah, `Can't mass-assign protected attributes: user_attributes`.  I tried putting `:user_attributes` in my `attr_accessible`, but then it said `Can't mass-assign protected attributes: email`, which is already in my `attr_accessible`

Comment: Is `email` `attr_accessible`'ed in `User` model or in `CustomerInfo` model? it needs to be `attr_accessible`'ed in `User`.

Comment: ok, now I'm running into the same problem I was with it in reverse... it's saying that the password can't be blank, but the password isn't even being filled out on this page...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20715/discussion-between-ahmad-sherif-and-jake)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using accepts_nested_attributes_for and attr_accessible, you'll have to include the user_attributes in the attr_accessible line or you won't be able to update the user record

```
attr_accessible :user_attributes
accepts_nested_attributes_for :user
```

Comment: Assuming order doesn't matter, I have exactly that, but still... nothing.